# HTTP ERROR 404 gwt:run maven application in vscode

Tags: maven, gwt

I just generated a default maven gwt application in command line using this :

```
$ mvn -B archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=gwt-maven-plugin \
    -DarchetypeVersion=2.8.1 \
    -DgroupId=com.mycompany \
    -DartifactId=my-app \
    -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT \
    -Dmodule=MyModule
```

However when I run `mvn clean gwt:run` I get an HTTP ERROR 404 not found in the browser.
What could possibly go wrong?
[image from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJrSG.png)

here is my pom.xml file.
I did add anything to it yet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>mycompany-api</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Maven Archetype for GWT</name>

  <properties>
    <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
    <gwt.version>2.8.1</gwt.version>

    <!-- GWT 2.8 requires 1.8 -->
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.release>1.8</maven.compiler.release>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <!-- Output classes directly into the webapp, so that IDEs and "mvn process-classes" update them in DevMode -->
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>

      <!-- Mojo's Maven Plugin for GWT -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>test</goal>
              <goal>generateAsync</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see 
          gwt-maven-plugin documentation at codehaus.org -->
        <configuration>
          <runTarget>module.html</runTarget>
          <modules>
            <module>com.mycompany.module</module>
          </modules>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

- One other thing to mention is if I run `mvn clean gwt:run` from vscode directly, I can't get to the browser once I click on lunch default browser. I get the error in the console like this :

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.8.1:run (default-cli) on project
> com.mycompany: Command failed with status 127: [ERROR] /bin/sh -c
> '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java' '-Xmx512m'
> 'com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode' '-gen'
> '/home/username/Documents/projects/mycompany/target/.generated' '-war'
> '/home/username/Documents/projects/mycompany/target/appname-1.0-SNAPSHOT'
> '-logLevel' 'INFO' '-port' '8888' '-codeServerPort' '9997'
> '-startupUrl' 'module.html' '-sourceLevel' '1.8'
> 'com.mycompany.appname

Comment: why not using the Thomas Broyer's gwt-maven-plugin?

Comment: @ElHoss : you're right, that is what I ended up doing. and it worked from the get go. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using the using the **Thomas Broyer's gwt-maven-plugin** archetypes instead. It was less complicated and it worked on the first trial. I will recommend it as it is also very well structured.

[I got the archetype here](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes)